# OTF Colour font not working with CSS Font Face

Tags: css, fonts

I made a custom font in Illustrator that's full colour, using FontMaker I was able to export this to an OTF font, now when I install the font it works as it should in illustrator, photoshop etc,

[SvenFont](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvdln.png)

But when I use CSS Font Face

`@font-face { font-family: SvenFont; src: url("/wp-content/uploads/2023/09/SvenFont.otf") format("opentype"); }`

It ends up just being plain black

[plain black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDF43.png)

I've checked to make sure its not inheriting any colours from the base CSS, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

I've tried converting it into different formats but to no avail.

Comment: There are quite a few different color font formats. Some are supported in some browsers while others may fallback to monochrome rendering. You may test your font different browsers and check  compatibility [here "chromacheck"](https://pixelambacht.nl/chromacheck/). The authors of this tool also made this great font inspector [wakamaifondue](https://wakamaifondue.com/) you can use to check which color format was used when compiling the font. See also this [css-tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/colrv1-and-css-font-palette-web-typography/)